# POST Requests seen as GET by server

Tags: apache, rest, http-verbs

Got a really strange problem here. When sending post requests to my PHP script

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

returns "GET" instead of "POST".

It works fine for every other REST method

so this is what I get

```
GET -> GET
POST-> GET
PUT -> PUT
DELETE -> DELETE
```

It only happens on one of my servers so i'm assuming it's an apache problem and i've managed to figure out that it only happens if I add "www" to my url.

I.e

www.something.com

causes the problem but

something.com

does not

I have tested on different sites on the same server and I get the same thing so I'm assuming it's  global config.

Any thoughts

Comment: hmm.. what is the subdomain if the form's action? they might be different subdomain with the current page. I'm not sure if that's a problem, but it's worth the try.

Comment: theyre not subdomains, each of the sites i've tried has it's own primary domain. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: try comparing the phpinfo() output

Comment: phpinfo() gives the same results as above. REQUEST_METHOD is still coming back as POST for GET requests.

Comment: _“it only happens if I add "www" to my url.”_ – do you have rewriting in place that redirects these requests to the non-www version? Redirects are always followed using GET, so you would lose the POST data at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [HTTP spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-24#section-6.4.2) says for response codes 301 and 302:

> Note: For historic reasons, a user agent MAY change the request method
> from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this behavior is
> undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code can be used
> instead

A third (but unlikely) possibility is you're getting a 303 response to the initial URI. The solution is twofold:

- Configure the clients which are under your control to POST to the canonical URI so they are not redirected at all.
- Configure your server to redirect using 307 in this case instead of 301/302.

Comment: right you put me on the right track and now I've fixed it. The problem was I didn't have www.something.com as a server alias I only had something.com. So It was forwarding instead of recognising it as a legitimate address. And then your forwarding problem was kicking in. Thanks!