# I can't send POST request from android volley to php

Tags: php, android, post

I'm using android volley StringRequest to send a post request to a PHP file which is already hosted online. This was working before but after the domain name was changed, this PHP file no longer receives the volley request as a post request. In the PHP file `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` returns GET instead of POST.

Here is the android volley request code snippet

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, postURL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d("MY_DEBUG",s);

        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
        {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            return parameters;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            //return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }

        //adding parameters to send
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("request", "edit_product");
            parameters.put("id", id);

            return parameters;
        }
    };

    request.setShouldCache(false);
    InitiateVolley.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

And here are the few first lines of code in the PHP file that handles the post request from an android volley

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
//it's a POST request, We are good to go...handle the post request.
}else{
  //not a POST request, kill it here
  echo "error";
  die();
}
```

What could be causing this issue? Is there a setting I have to do on the PHP side? Or maybe the PHP version of the new domain? Please help out

Comment: try checking it with some REST tool, Postman for example

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Postman still sees it as a GET request. I just tried it now

Comment: Try removing getBodyContentType() method and getHeaders() method.

Comment: then as you can see, it does not relate to Android. Try logging `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` value on the PHP side, for example return it instead of ``error` in `else`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` returned GET. I used Postman to check

Comment: And you are sure that you set the method to POST in postman?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I'm very sure. I've noticed the error is from the RESTful api.

Comment: @Wijdan I've done that and it didn't work

Comment: then the problem is clearly with PHP side, and it looks like you have nothing to do with it from coding side. Probably the server is missconfigured

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189582/discussion-between-nnabugwu-michael-uchechukwu-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the "www" from the url and it solved my problem. This SO question [POST Requests seen as GET by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049223/post-requests-seen-as-get-by-server) helped